# Get the original expression passed as an argument to a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a function find out the original expression which was used as an argument to a function.
Example:

```
def fun(var):
    exp_var = <some magic>
    print "%s = %s"%(exp_var, var)
```

so that:

```
>>> fun(4.5+2*2)
```

will print

```
4.5+2*2 = 8.5
```

I think there should be a way using python's inspect module but I couldn't find how.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?